# Is it possible to mirror packages from packager.io?

Tags: yum, mirror

Is it possible to mirror packages from packager.io[0] to an internal yum repository server/mirror?

[0] http://packager.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the packages are exposed as a Yum repository, then use the `reposync` utility (from the yum-utils package on a RHEL/CentOS host). See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016 for examples.